# Array of arrays using React useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Why is it that this works:

```
let [thisState, setThisState] = useState([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]);
```

works, but this doesn't

```
let [thisState, setThisState] = useState([])
setThisState([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']])
```

They're getting the same value input, but setThisState() really doesn't like the array of Arrays.

Sorry for not posting my initial code beforehand.
I'm using a Component to render in a calendar, fromServerToLocal takes what exists in the database to a format the Calendar component can use.

```
import styles from '../../styles/Home.module.scss'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar'
import moment from 'moment'
import withDragAndDrop from "react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop/withDragAndDrop"
import "react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop/styles.css"
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'




const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment)
const DnDCalendar = withDragAndDrop(Calendar)
export default function calendar() {
  let [serverEventList, setServerEventList] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {


    async function go() {
      const res = await fetch('/api/endPoint', {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        method: 'GET'
      })

      let response = await res.json();

      return await response
    }
    go().then(x => {
      console.log(x);
      setServerEventList({ data: x })
    })



  }, [])

  function fromServerToLocal(serverObject) {
    let finishedArray = [];
    serverObject.forEach((entry, index) => {

      finishedArray.push({

        start: entry.startDate,
        end: entry.endDate,
        title: entry.firstName + " " + entry.lastName,
        resourceId: index
      })
    })

    return finishedArray;
  }
  function translateData(arrayOfObjects) {
    let properArray = []
    arrayOfObjects.forEach((entry) => {
      properArray.push({
        start: entry[0],
        end: entry[1],
        title: entry[2],
        resourceId: entry[3]
      })
    })
    console.log(`this: ${properArray}`)

    return properArray
  }
  return (

    <div className={styles.container}>

      <h1>Calendar</h1>
      <Head>
        <title>Calendar</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Rent a bike" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <DnDCalendar
        defaultDate={moment().toDate()}
        defaultView="month"
        localizer={localizer}
        events={fromServerToLocal(serverEventList)}
        resizable
        style={{ height: 500 }}
      />
      <p>    event: {serverEventList}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What makes you conclude it doesn't work?

Comment: useState() hook is async, may be the console just below the hook does not work as expected.

Comment: @jonrsharpe getting a runtime error, "Objects are not valid as a React child, If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: Based on that error, it's not about the array of arrays but about how you're trying to render that data.  An example would be great (as mentioned above)

Comment: hopefully this edit is helpful in explaining whats happening

Comment: @michaelhall Better, but please include the entire component's code. Remember, we see only what you write in the question.

Comment: The component is kind of large, you sure you want it all?

Comment: Theres the full file.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work as-is. To verify you can log the changed state inside `useEffect`. You'll see the updated value.

```
let [thisState, setThisState] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
    setThisState([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']])
}, [])
useEffect(() => console.log(thisState), [thisState]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to organize it a little bit like this:

```
    const initialState = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']];

    let [thisState, setThisState] = useState(initialState);
```

to improve readability and to make sure there are no typos on the declaration of the initial state, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setServerEventList({data: x})`

Comment: In that case, I get an error saying evts.filter is not a function.

Comment: After sharing the code, we can see the issues in accessing the results returned from fetch API calls.